# Datastructure Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have implemented a custom Linkedlist and i could not find the result i expected as it is unable to rectify the issue.

```
package LinkedList;

public class Node {

protected Node nextNode;
protected int data;

public Node(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}


package LinkedList;

public class LinkedList {

private Node head;

public void insertLast(int data) {

    Node new_node = new Node(data);

    if(head == null) {
        head = new_node;
    }else {

        Node n = head;

        while(n.nextNode != null) {
            n = n.nextNode;
        }   

        n.nextNode = new_node;
    }   
}

public void insertFirst(int data) {

    Node new_node = new Node(data);

    if(head == null) {

        head = new_node;

    }else {

        Node node = head;
        head = new_node;
        head.nextNode = node;

    }

}

public void insertAt(int index,int data) {

    int x = 1;

    Node node = head;

    while(node != null) {

        if(index == 0) {

            insertFirst(data);
            break;

        }else {

            node = node.nextNode;

            if( index == x ) {

                Node new_node = new Node(data);
                Node current = node;
                node = new_node;
                node.nextNode = current;
                break;
            }

            x++;

        }

    }

}

public void print() {

    Node node = head;

    while(node != null) {
        System.out.println(node.data);
        node = node.nextNode;
    }

}
```

}

```
package Test;

import LinkedList.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.insertLast(100);
    list.insertLast(200);
    list.insertLast(300);
    list.insertLast(400);
    list.insertLast(500);

    list.insertAt(1, 50);

    list.print();

}

}
```

The issue occurs when working with adding an element to a specific location. when printing out the result, the element does not get added to the list where I had a hard time debugging the code to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insertion in `insertAt()` misses the new node entirely. You want to add the element in between two nodes so you are changing from `node1 -> node2` to `node1 -> new_node -> node2`. You need to modify the next node of node1 to the new node, and make sure that the new node points to node2. Try code like this:

```
public void insertAt(int index,int data) {
    //assumes index <= size of linked list
    int curr = 1;

    if(index < 0)
        return;

    if(index == 0){
        insertFirst(data);
        return;
    }

    Node currNode = head;
    while( curr < index){
        currNode = currNode.nextNode;
        curr++;
    }

    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.nextNode = currNode.nextNode;
    currNode.nextNode = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Do you find any fault with my logic?. By the way, I appreciate your answer and it is correct. I just want to figure out what went wrong logically in my code. Please note that i have modified my code at else if part in the insertAt(int dat.....) as below, 

//

}else {
  
Node n = node.nextNode;
   
while(n != null) {
    
System.out.println("asd : "+n.nextNode.data);
    
if( index == x) {
     
Node new_node = new Node(data);
Node current = n;
n = new_node;
n.nextNode = current;
break;
     
}
x++; 
n = n.nextNode;
}
}

Comment: the new code has a good number of errors. for example you have `while(n != null)` and then `print(n.nextNode.data)`, this will lead to null pointer exceptions as you haven't ensured that the current node has a neighbor. Your assignment logic goes like this (where currNode is n): `currNode -> nextNode`, becomes `newNode -> currNode -> nextNode`. You are doing unnecessary checks after the current node and assigning the new node before that. That is all through loops and conditionals that don't quite make sense.

Comment: @Farhan Dulip I would recommend doing an example linked list on paper and adding at specific indices. Try to explain your process in the simplest terms and then replicate in code. There are a lot of good resources out there as well for linked list creation and help. [example](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-add-element-at-specific-index-in-linkedlist-example/)